Get Page title and add to the record
I use this code as webhook for intergrating Contact Form 7 in WordPress with Bitrix CRM. But I also need to get current page title where my form located and add to the JSON record as well. How can I make it?
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function');
function your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function($contact_form)
{
    // Перехватываем данные из Contact Form 7
    $title = $contact_form->title;
//    $posted_data = $contact_form->posted_data;

    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    $firstName = $posted_data['your-name'];
    $yourEmail = $posted_data['your-email'];
    $yourPhone = $posted_data['your-phone'];

    $queryUrl = 'https://****.bitrix24.eu/***/crm.lead.add';
    $queryData = '{"fields":{"TITLE": "'.$title.'","NAME": "'.$firstName.'", "STATUS_ID": "NEW", "OPENED": "Y", "PHONE": [ { "VALUE": "'.$yourPhone.'", "VALUE_TYPE": "WORK" } ],"EMAIL": [ { "VALUE": "'.$yourEmail.'", "VALUE_TYPE": "WORK" } ],"SOURCE_ID": "WEB"},"params": { "REGISTER_SONET_EVENT": "Y" }}';
    if($yourEmail == null || $yourEmail == ''){
        $queryData = '{"fields":{"TITLE": "'.$title.'","NAME": "'.$firstName.'", "STATUS_ID": "NEW", "OPENED": "Y", "PHONE": [ { "VALUE": "'.$yourPhone.'", "VALUE_TYPE": "WORK" } ],"SOURCE_ID": "WEB"},"params": { "REGISTER_SONET_EVENT": "Y" }}';
    }
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://****.bitrix24.eu/***/crm.lead.add',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $queryData,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
//    echo $response;
//    if (array_key_exists('error', $response)) echo "Ошибка при сохранении лида: " . $response['error_description'] . "<br/>";

    $result = json_decode($response, 1);
    if (array_key_exists('error', $result)) echo "Ошибка при сохранении лида: ".$result['error_description']."<br/>";

}


You can use special tags in Cf7 which contains several info, you can find another similar question here: How to get post title by contact form 7 and the official documentation here: https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/
Those can be used inside your form email content and will be valorized with the actual value when you send the email.
In your case adding those to the email message body won't work so you need to use a plugins instead: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/#description
It has a lot of feature but the one you are searching is adding this:
[dynamic_hidden my_post_title "CF7_get_current_var key='title'"]

This has to be placed inside the contact form body and will add an hidden field inside the page HTML. You can later fetch this by using:
 $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

$posted_data['my_post_title'] <---- this
Tested & works
